# Speed of MySQL SELECT (are indexes worth it on columns with little variation)?

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, where-clause

I've done plenty of searching/reading on this topic, but I'm still at a loss for a solution.

I have tables with tens or hundreds of thousands of rows, totaling somewhere in the area of 300GB of data. The column I need to select contains a lot of HTML, which may be part of the problem. I am using COMPRESS. The query contains two WHERE clauses:

```
 SELECT id, olr_id, COMPRESS(source_html) 
 FROM buildings 
 WHERE scrape_status=1 
 AND parse_status=0 LIMIT 1;
```

As one might expect, id is a primary key. Additionally, olr_id is a unique index. This query takes something like 160-300sec just to return a result, which is completely unfeasible. Strangely (at least to me), removing the WHERE clause for `parse_status` results in the query completing in under 2-3 seconds. At first, I thought maybe this was because it was too specific, so I even tried removing `scrape_status` and only running the `parse_status` WHERE clause, but apparently it's this specific clause causing the insane increase in execution time.

The thing is, I don't know if indexing these columns would even do any good (`scrape_status` and `parse_status`), because their range of values is 0-2. I guess that's my main question -- would it help to index a column with such a small variance in values? I read somewhere once that indexing is really best for columns with great variation, but as I said, I'm at a loss for ideas, and 160-300 seconds is just totally unreasonable for hundreds of thousands of records.

Any input would be appreciated greatly. If you need additional input to help me, I'd be glad to provide. On that note, these are the EXPLAIN results for each of the three queries:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: building
type: ALL
possible_keys: null
key: null
key_len: null
ref: null
rows: 58664
Extra: Using where
```

I appreciate your time in reading and offering any assistance that you may.

Comment: Just an idea, I'm not even sure how you would do it but i think it is possible for you to mark the halfway point of your table and then run two queries simultaneously (forking or something like that) with one going through the first half, and one going through second half of your table.

Comment: If you added a compound index on parse and scrape status, the query would be well quick. The index as you say would be painful. Why are you getting the value you want like this, as in first one the DBMS bumps into, (Limit 1) ?

Comment: @CppandQtBeginner I'll look into that as a possible solution.

Comment: How long does the query take if you remove `compress(source_html)` from it?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Will look into the compound index, too. I'm getting the values like this because it's in an "infinite" loop, fetching the first unparsed record, and then parsing it. How might you recommend doing this instead?

Comment: @Barmar 1.6 seconds (a much more reasonable amount of time).

Comment: In that case, I think the second solution in my answer should be all you need.

Comment: @EthanBarron, if i was doing something like that, I'd keep unparsed records in their own table and them move them in to a parsed table as they got sorted out. Add a processing state flag and you can band it in a back ground task, possibly parallel process them. Might have to twiddle a bit with other functions that work on parsed and unparsed records, simple union though.

Answer (score 2):

Create a composite index of both columns in the `WHERE` clause:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_sp ON buildings (scrape_status, parse_status);
```

Although each of them by itself doesn't partition the table too much, the combination probably does.

Try the following as well:

```
SELECT b1.id, olr_id, COMPRESS(source_html)
from buildings b1
JOIN (SELECT id
      FROM buildings 
      WHERE scrape_status=1 
      AND parse_status=0
      LIMIT 1) b2
USING (id)
```

Your original query may be compressing all matching rows, even though most of them are thrown out by the `LIMIT` clause. This version only compresses the one selected row.

Comment: No, MySQL does not evaluate expressions in the select-list for rows until it determines that they match the conditions in the WHERE clause.  You can test this:  `SELECT SLEEP(1) FROM SomeTable WHERE unindexed_column=123` and see if it sleeps as many seconds as the number of rows in the table, or as the number of rows that have value 123.

Comment: @BillKarwin The issue isn't the WHERE clause, it's the LIMIT clause.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the great answer. You also lead me to a second (maybe a little easier) idea. I noticed if I run the query without selecting `source_html`, it's much faster. I can select without, find the ID of the first matching row, and then select the source_html of this row. I'm going to give this a shot and see what happens before dealing with all the index updates.

Comment: That's exactly what this join is doing, but it does it in one query instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the indexed column doesn't have many distinct values, an index is beneficial in cases when the value you're searching for is uncommon.  In other words, the index helps when the search is more *selective*, and matches a small percentage of rows.

So in this case, the decision about creating an index is based on what percentage of rows match your conditions `scrape_status=1` and `parse_status=0`.  For example, suppose `scrape_status=1` matches 2% of rows, and `parse_status=0` matches 1% of rows, I'd want to use `parse_status` as the leading column for the index.

If that's the case, but nearly all rows with `parse_status=0` also have `scrape_status=1`, then there may be little additional benefit to making a compound index.  Whereas if `scrape_status=1` is effective at further restricting the matching rows, then you'd definitely want it to be built into the index.

MySQL also has optimizations for LIMIT. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html  It tries to bail out of the query as soon as it finds the desired number of matching rows.  MySQL 5.6 has added some new optimizations in this area.

MYSQL does not calculate the select-list expressions for rows that don't match conditions in the WHERE clause.

However, MySQL *does* have to read rows of data from disk to evaluate them against the conditions in the WHERE clause.  This I/O is the source of a lot of performance cost, and it's the reason that narrowing down the search with indexes is so important.  And if your `source_html` column is a TEXT column containing long strings, it's likely that this adds further overhead to the I/O, because MySQL will have to read additional pages of data from disk (see [Blob Storage in Innodb](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/) for more details).